# How to abort getpass in case it cannot hide the password

Tags: python

I would like to make it totally sure that an user does not type in a visible password by mistake.

How can I make sure my code aborts in case python's getpass cannot hide the password?

Trying to convert the warning into an exception does not seem to work. For instance

```
warnings.simplefilter('error')
password = getpass.getpass("Give me a password, please:")
```

does not exit with an exception rather than prompting for the password. The other way round it prompts for the password and then complains about a not caught exception.